# how to put nested list symbols on the same line

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve this in IE10/Win32:

```
    1. a. Item 1a
       b. Item 1b
    2. a. Item 2a
       b. Item 2b
```

?

Using

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
  <li>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
      <li>Item 1a</li>
      <li>Item 1b</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
      <li>Item 1a</li>
      <li>Item 1b</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

I achieve this (with empty lines next to 1., 2.):

```
    1.
       a. Item 1a
       b. Item 1b
    2. 
       a. Item 2a
       b. Item 2b
```

Comment: i dont get any empty line (http://jsfiddle.net/J2dA3/) check whether u have any style for "ol"

Comment: code working fine [http://jsfiddle.net/JUpQW/]

Comment: Please include your css, you must have a property making the blank line and we can't find it without your CSS.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question. Not using any CSS. In Chrome and Firefox I get no empty lines. However, in IE10 I get empty lines next to 1., 2. Any idea what CSS to use to get rid of them?